# Export a CSV using lightning Component without DOM modification

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, security-review, dom

**Lightning Controller**

```
getData : function(component, file, fileContents) {        
    var action = component.get("c.data");

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var csvContent = response.getReturnValue();

        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);

            //Security review states that the below code violates DOM Modification rule
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
            link.setAttribute("download", "data.csv");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);         
},
```

other try was using `window.open(encodedUri)`
is there any possibility to download `.csv` in Lightning Component without manipulating DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers support [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), meaning that you can do this:

---

## app

```
<aura:application >
    <ui:button label="Download" press="{!c.download}" />
</aura:application>
```

## controller

```
({
    download: function(component, event, helper) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = "data:text/csv,base64;ImhlbGxvIiwid29ybGQiCg==";
        a.download = "text.csv";
        a.click();
    }
})
```

The file will download automatically or provide a prompt for the user, depending on the browser. It is not necessary to add the link to the DOM for this to work.

In practice, you'll want to base64 encode your return value in Apex, so you can append it directly:

```
getData : function(component, file, fileContents) {        
    var action = component.get("c.data");

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var csvContent = response.getReturnValue();

        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = "data:text/csv;base64,"+csvContent;
            link.download = "data.csv";
            link.click();

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);         
},
```

Comment: security review rejected us stating that 
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);var link = document.createElement("a"); is Lightning: Controller DOM Modification Violation

Comment: @SaravananBaskar Hmm, not sure then. I'll have to research it some more. I feel like that's an illegitimate concern.

Comment: @SaravananBaskar I believe sfdcfox is right, since we are not appending the created anchor tag it shouldn't be flagged as **Controller DOM Modification Violation**. Can you create a case and reach out to the Partner community with case id, you'll surely get some help there.

Comment: @SaravananBaskar When our component was security reviewed, there was one place DOM manipulation was done in the helper and Security Review team flagged it. But what's interesting was, we didn't have a **controller** at all in the component and all DOM manipulating code were invoked from the **Renderer**.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox and Praveen for your clarification and help!! Our app passed the test!!